# (Python3.7) take the words of a phrase that start with a consonat and store them in a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, reverse

I wanted to do a programme that:
1.Received a phrase as a string and turned it into a list of words
2.checked if every element(word) of that list started with a vowel or a consonant
3.Stored the words started with a a vowel in a list and the words started with a consonant in another list
4.Reverse the order of the letters in the words started with a consonant
5.Showed a final phrase  similar to the first with the words started by consonants reversed and those started by vowels unchanged.

In my work I had to define a function that says if the word starts with a vowel or consonant.
I tried to do it but it only seemed to work for the first element started with a vowel.
Can you help me finding out what is wrong? Can you provide me with a clue about the 5th step?
Ps:I search about this problem but only found solutions that included operations like .lower which I am not allowed to use.

My Code:
    startsVowel=[]

```
startsConsonant=[]

vowels=["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]

i=input()

def detectWords(input):
    x=input.split(" ")
    return x
print(detectWords(i))

def VowelBeginning(x):
   for s in x:
       a=list(s)
       if a[0] in vogais:
            startsVowel.append(s)
            print(startsVowels)
       return(startsVowels)

       if a[0] not in vowels:
           startsConsonant.append(s)
        print(startsConsonant)
    return(startsConsonant)
print(VowelBeginning(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
s = input('Sentence: ')

print(' '.join([x if x.lower().startswith(('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')) else x[::-1] for x in s.split()]))
```

This splits the sentence into words, checks if word starts with a consonant or vowel. This then reverses all words that start with consonant (those starting with vowel are unchanged) and forms the sentence back.

**Sample run**:

```
Sentence: Apple Ball Cat Dog Elephant
Apple llaB taC goD Elephant
```

Comment: what is the meaning of the operation join?

Comment: The thing is: in my work I have to specifically define a function VowelBeginnng, I am not allowed to take short-cuts.

Comment: @AnaHelenaVieira, `.join()` gets the strings which are words back into sentence. We specify join by space (`' '.join(..)`) so you join the words by space.

Comment: @AnaHelenaVieira, I don't understand why you need to define a function in that name. May be you can add this to your function and return it, seems unnecessary though.

Comment: @AnaHelenaVieira, can we have a different name for the function atleast?

Comment: @AnaHelenaVieira, you can add my code to your function and don't print. Instead store to a variable say 'a' and at the end of function `return a`.

Comment: I have to define another function for inversion so I can't.The problem is that I have been around this problem for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the indentation of your return statement. During your loop you are appending words to a list, you should return the list at the end of your loop.
With a code looking like :

```
def startsVowel(x):
    for s in x:
        if s[0] in b:
            c.append(s)
    return(c)
```

Comment: You're right!But what about the main code? How do I fix it? Where shall return be?